# Linear independence of tensors

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a domain with fraction field $K$ and $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module. If $x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n\, \in M$ are $R$- linearly independent, then $1\otimes x_1, 1\otimes x_2,\ldots, 1\otimes x_n$ are $K$-linearly independent in $K \otimes_R M$.

Attempt:

Let $\sum_ic_i (1 \otimes x_i)=0$ for $c_i \in K$. Then we can write $c_i=\frac{a_i}{b}$ for some $a_i, b \in R$. Thus,$\frac{1}{b} \otimes \sum_i a_ix_i=0$.

If I could show that this implies $\sum_i a_ix_i$ is in the torsion module of $M$, then there exists some $0\neq  r \in R$ such that $r \sum_i a_ix_i=\sum_i ra_ix_i=0$ implying $a_i=0$ since $x_i$ are linearly independent and $R$ is a domain. This would show $c_i=\frac{a_i}{b}=\frac{0}{b}=0$ and thus the conclusion.

So, is it true that $\sum_i a_ix_i$ is in the torsion module of $M$? How can I prove it?

Comment: If $1/b\otimes\sum a_ix_i=0$, so is $\sum a_ix_i$. Use the fact the kernel of $M\to K\otimes_R M$ is precisely the torsion.